# VBA Addon in Outlook for password protect attachement files

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin

Im looking for VBA Addon for Outlook, something similar as add atechement but before file is attached i have to choose and type password, in result, file will be password protected.

Is this even possible ?

Comment: What type of file?

Answer (score 1):

There is no password attachment protection in Outlook, or in email in general.